# Quotient Spaces and Dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, quotient-spaces, change-of-basis

> Y is a subspace of a finite-dimensional linear space X. Let $y_1,...y_j$ be a basis for Y, j=dimY. Then this set can be completed to form a basis for X by adjoining $x_{j+1}, ...,x_n$, n=dimX. Since $y_1,...,x_n$ form a basis for X, every x in X can be expressed as x=$\sum a_i y_i + \sum b_k x_k$. It follows that [x]=$\sum b_k [x_k]$, where [$\cdot$] denotes cosets.

I have trouble with the last sentence. Here is my work:

$\sum b_k [x_k]=\sum b_k (x_k +Y)=\sum_{j+1}^{n} b_k x_k + Y$.

However, since {$x_{j+1},... x_n$} does not span X, i.e. x$\neq \sum b_k x_k$, I cannot understand how [x]=$\sum b_k [x_k]$.

Comment: The symbol $[x]$ denotes an equivalence class of vectors: $[x] = [x']$ whenever $x-x'$ lies in $Y$. In your case, $[x] = \sum b_k [x_k]$ since the difference $x - \sum b_k x_k = \sum a_i y_i$ is an element of $Y$. Remember that in the quotient $X/Y$, elements of $Y$ are all identified with the coset  $[0]$ of $0$, and so are forgotten.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $y\in Y$ then $[x+y]=[x]$.

**Proof**.  By definition,
$$[u]=\{u+v\mid v\in Y\}\ .$$
So if $z\in[x+y]$ then
$$\eqalign{
  &z=(x+y)+v\qquad\hbox{for some $v\in Y$}\cr
  \Rightarrow\quad&z=x+(y+v)\cr
  \Rightarrow\quad&z\in[x]\qquad\hbox{since $y+v\in Y$.}\cr}$$
Thus $[x+y]\subseteq[x]$.  You can similarly show $[x]\subseteq[x+y]$ (try it), so $[x+y]=[x]$.

So in your problem,
$$[x]=[\textstyle\sum a_i y_i + \sum b_k x_k]=[\sum b_k x_k]\ ,$$
and the rest is as in your post.